# twisted Proxy request modification methods

Tags: http, proxy, twisted

How can I view the requests sent by a twisted proxy server which part of twisted.web.proxy should I be looking at. The aim is to add extra headers before dataReceived is sent to the destination server.
 For example adding an extra header like "Xzone: foo.com\r" to all proxied requests so that the final request looks like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Xzone: foo.com\r
Host: bbb.com\r
User-Agent: mozilla\r
Accept: */*\r
```

Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: You might want to add the header after the `GET` line.

Comment: trying to do something custom. But also wondering how such custom requests can be achieved. The browser sends normal requests and the twisted proxy adds the Xzone: header above the GET request.

Comment: The example in the question is not a legal HTTP request.  If that's really what you want to do then I don't think Twisted Web is going to help you a whole lot (because Twisted Web is for HTTP not not-quite-HTTP).

Comment: Okay so like You had suggested earlier adding the header after the GET line..How can this still be achived with the data passing through a twisted proxy. What method should I override.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `twisted.web.proxy` is rather crufty and was not written with this kind of customization in mind.  However, it is possible to inject new headers into the proxied request in a number of different ways.  The general idea is to hook into one of the steps in processing of the request and modify the request headers so they include your new header.

For example, you could hook in to `ProxyRequest.process`:

```
from twisted.web.proxy import ProxyRequest

class ChangeSomeHeadersProxyRequest(ProxyRequest):
    def process(self):
        self.changeHeaders()
        return ProxyRequest.process(self)

    def changeHeaders(self):
        # Inject an extra request header.
        self.requestHeaders.addRawHeader(b"Xzone", b"foo.com")
```

Then hook this up to the rest of your proxy:

```
from twisted.web.proxy import Proxy
from twisted.web.server import Site

class ChangeSomeHeadersSite(Site):
    protocol = Proxy
    requestFactory = ChangeSomeHeadersProxyRequest
```

Now set up a `ChangeSomeHeadersSite` as you would a regular `Site`.

Comment: Here is a pic from wireshark that shows what Im trying to achive ![request][1] [1]http://imgur.com/AR3hYPj @Jean-Paul Calderone

Comment: Sorry, that picture confuses me quite a bit.  It looks like a connection that receives an HTTP request and then another HTTP request and then sends an HTTP response.  Two requests with one response isn't legal HTTP.  Perhaps there's some pipelining going on here?  But you didn't mention that in your question so I'm not sure.  Maybe you could edit your question so that it more completely describes the behavior you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Have decided to create a new question that shows exactly what Im trying to achieve.